# understanding where and when rails code runs( js.erb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

Please i need an explanation on how ruby codes in javascript files are been executed in rails.
i need to know why the code below would run

```
var path = '<%= "#{Rails.root}/public/time_table/time_table.json" %>';
```

and

```
<% file = File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/time_table/time_table.json",'r') %>
```

would not.
where and when do JavaScript files get executed in rails.
when the application sees a ruby code syntax in a **filename.js.erb** file, how those it treat it. Please i really need this explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is executed in the browser. `js.erb` files are *templates* for the code that will be sent and executed in the browser.

In your first example the ERB template will result in:

```
var path = '/path/to/root/public/time_table/time_table.json';
```

This JavaScript will be sent and run by the browser.

In your second example you won't insert any text into the output (you used `<%` instead of `<%=`). The code between `<%` and `%>` is *Ruby*. It opens the file for reading and assigns to `file`. **It doesn't read the file or otherwise insert anything into the output**.

In general, `ERB` is used to generate content that will be sent to the browser. `html.erb` is for HTML code. `js.erb` is for JavaScript code. The templates are expanded on the server and the resulting output is sent to the browser.

**Added based on comments**. To show the content of the file you need to read it. `File.new` just opens it and allows you to manipulate the file (read, write, truncate, etc.). I recommend you read the file with `File.read` and insert it into the template with:

```
<%= raw File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/time_table/time_table.json") %>
```

You may also consider moving the file to a partial, e.g. `app/views/time_tables/_time_table.json.erb` and rendering in the controller with:

```
render partial: 'time_tables/time_table.json.erb'
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Greg Navis, i don't get your explanation for my second example. If am to actually read the file, what am i to do??

Comment: @lilfancy, what do you want to do with the content of that file? Assign to a JavaScript variable?

Comment: My pleasure, @lilfancy.